# Breeze - Get SharePoint AttachmentFiles from List using Expand?

Tags: sharepoint, breeze

I am using Breeze with a SharePoint Online list, which support attachments. The Breeze query, correctly calls expand and I can see through Browser and Fiddler, that JSON is returned with the attachment data in it. However, the entities created in Breeze JavaScript don't contain data for AttachmentFiles. Its always Null. Is this something the SP Adapter just doesn't support, or am I defining the AttachmentFiles and List entities incorrectly. I have tried numerous ways to define relationship, using complextype and navigation, with autogen ID and without, but I am coming up stumped.

Rest Request looks like this: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Contacts')/items?$expand=Author/Id,AttachmentFiles&$select=Id,AuthorId,FirstName,Title,Email,Author,AttachmentFiles ,Author/UserName

Attached is a view of the JSON returned, and the current Breeze entities mapped.

Snippet from entities

```
    //attachments
addType({
  name: 'AttachmentFiles',
  dataProperties: {
    ServerRelativeUrl: {
      nullable: false
    },
    FileName: {
      nullable: false
    }

  }
});

// create entity for contacts
addType({
  name: 'Contacts',
  defaultResourceName: 'getbytitle(\'Contacts\')/items',
  dataProperties: {
    Id: {
      type: breeze.DataType.Int32
    },
    AuthorId: {
      type: breeze.DataType.Int32
    },
    FirstName: {
      nullable: false
    },
    Title: {
      nullable: false
    }, // this is actually the last name field in the list
    Email: {
      nullable: false,
      validators: [breeze.Validator.emailAddress()]
    },
    Author: {
      complexTypeName: "Author"
    }
  },
  // Let model.validation add the requireReferenceEntity validators
  navigationProperties: {
    AttachmentFiles: {
      type: 'AttachmentFiles',
      hasMany: true
    }
  }
});
```

See JSON response below

```
{
"d": {
    "results": [
        {
            "__metadata": {
                "id": "388762a5-a565-4033-af90-5a2ea4cb1894",
                "uri": "https://foo-616175366e015f.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/_api/Web/Lists(guid'df211835-f6df-4bb0-b7f0-0995c6ff8562')/Items(1)",
                "etag": "\"3\"",
                "type": "SP.Data.ContactsListItem"
            },
            "AttachmentFiles": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "https://foo-616175366e015f.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/_api/Web/Lists(guid'df211835-f6df-4bb0-b7f0-0995c6ff8562')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles('8328787dc792224f625c9645a45d01aa.jpg')",
                            "uri": "https://foo-616175366e015f.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/_api/Web/Lists(guid'df211835-f6df-4bb0-b7f0-0995c6ff8562')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles('8328787dc792224f625c9645a45d01aa.jpg')",
                            "type": "SP.Attachment"
                        },
                        "FileName": "8328787dc792224f625c9645a45d01aa.jpg",
                        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/Lists/Contacts/Attachments/1/8328787dc792224f625c9645a45d01aa.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        "__metadata": {
                            "id": "https://foo-616175366e015f.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/_api/Web/Lists(guid'df211835-f6df-4bb0-b7f0-0995c6ff8562')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles('Screen Shot 2015-04-23 at 10.28.35 AM.png')",
                            "uri": "https://foo-616175366e015f.sharepoint.com/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/_api/Web/Lists(guid'df211835-f6df-4bb0-b7f0-0995c6ff8562')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles('Screen%20Shot%202015-04-23%20at%2010.28.35%20AM.png')",
                            "type": "SP.Attachment"
                        },
                        "FileName": "Screen Shot 2015-04-23 at 10.28.35 AM.png",
                        "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/DevSIte/BreezeSP2013Sample/Lists/Contacts/Attachments/1/Screen Shot 2015-04-23 at 10.28.35 AM.png"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Author": {
                "__metadata": {
                    "id": "1fdc1547-d439-42bd-b3aa-b41e92c8ec6f",
                    "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
                },
                "UserName": "user@contoso.com"
            },
            "Id": 1,
            "ID": 1,
            "Title": "Alanso",
            "AuthorId": 1073741823,
            "FirstName": "Fernando",
            "Email": "fernando.alonso@ferrari.it"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I do see problems here ... that you can cure.

First, I'd like to call your attention to "[Debugging query results](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/query-debugging.html)" documentation which has many tips to help you diagnose what's going on. Not all of them are applicable but they are valuable clues in there.

I'm curious if your `EntityManager` has any entities of type "AttachmentFiles". I rather doubt it. You might check.

Regardless, two observations leap out at me:

1. The `AttachmentFiles` type does not have a key property, the property that uniquely identifies an instance of this type. Every `EntityType` must have at least one key property. The `MetadataHelper` can detect some keys by convention but there is no obvious candidate in your `AttachmentFiles`. If there is one (and I don't see it), you'll have to specify it.

> I'm assuming that you're using the `MetadataHelper` defined in Breeze Labs *breeze.metadata-helper.js* to write your metadata rather than the raw Breeze API for that purpose. It looks like you are doing so ... and that's a good thing.

2. Your `Contacts` type identifies a One-to-Many navigation to `AttachmentFiles` but doesn't specify the foreign key relationship in `AttachmentFiles` that would link instances of `AttachmentFiles` back to `Contacts`. Thus even if Breeze created `AttachmentFiles` instances from this JSON payload, it could not associate them with any instances of `Contacts`

I don't see anything in the data that supports the notion that `AttachmentFiles` are actually entities. They seem to be embedded in the `Contact` type.

There IS a way to represent that. But I'd want some confirmation before I went down that road. Maybe you can clarify some of the points I raised here before we propose next steps.

Comment: Thanks for response. The JSON response for AttachmenFiles doesn't include an ID column. It has FileName and ServerRelativeURL. I tried adding a autogen column, but that didn't seem to do anything. I also tried adding FK from Contacts entity to AttachmentFiles entity, and that also didn't seem to do anything. Maybe my syntax was incorrect, but I don't think so. I am using the SharePoint adapter from Breeze. When  debug, I have that AttachmenFiles object (property) on the Contacts object, but it is null. I will work through you debugging link. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Does `AttachmentFiles` have a FK to `Contacts` in SharePoint? If it does, we just have to expose it and adjust from there. If it doesn't then we can do some juijitsu to add the AF data to the contact data as they arrive or go really nuts w/ more Breeze magic. I got tricks up my sleeves.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't have FK. Its just a sub item in the result set. At this point, I am thinking I need to change the logic of my app, so I don't get AttachmentFiles as part of the Contact item, but have a separate call to AttachmentFiles Rest query

Comment: Are you sure? The OData `expand` would seem to imply entities related via some kind of FK even if it isn't obvious how you'd expose it. How could you make "a separate call to AF Rest query" w/o an FK. I wish I knew more SharePoint. Maybe we need Andrew Connell on this. If it truly is a nested "sub item", do you intend to update it? If not I have a quick & dirty solution for you (one I wouldn't want to use often).

Comment: Indeed there is no FK in AttachmenFiles. You can get all AttachmentFiles for an item by querying the contact item ID, but I can never see the item ID on the AttachmenFiles response. e.g. _api/web/lists/getbytitle('Classifieds')/items('1')/AttachmentFiles would get all attachments for contact item with id of 1. I don't plan to update the data, just read.